# Error install hhvm with macport and fail all install with macport

Tags: macos, python-2.7, port, macports, hhvm

I tried to install HHVM on Mac OS X Yosemite, but it failed and at last I can not make any installation MacPort.

For example, if I try to install pear , with this command line:

`sudo port install php55-pear`

Result :

```html
--->  Computing dependencies for php55-pear
--->  Cleaning php55-pear
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 29 broken file(s), matching files to ports  
--->  Found 6 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     boost @1.55.0 +no_single+no_static+python27
     libdlna @0.2.4 
     harfbuzz-icu @0.9.25 
     webkit-gtk3 @2.2.3 +video
     php54-intl @5.4.16 
     openldap @2.4.31 
--->  Computing dependencies for python27
--->  Staging python27 into destroot
Error: org.macports.destroot for port python27 returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port python27 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error rebuilding boost
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_target" line 96)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

    # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)
```

in log file (/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log) :

```html
version:1
:msg:main --->  Computing dependencies for python27:info:main .:debug:main python27 has no conflicts
:debug:main Searching for dependency: gettext
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for gettext
:debug:main Searching for dependency: zlib
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for zlib
:debug:main Searching for dependency: openssl
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for openssl
:debug:main Searching for dependency: sqlite3
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for sqlite3
:debug:main Searching for dependency: db48
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for db48
:debug:main Searching for dependency: ncurses
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for ncurses
:debug:main Searching for dependency: bzip2
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for bzip2
:debug:main Searching for dependency: libedit
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for libedit
:debug:main Searching for dependency: python_select
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for python_select
:debug:main Searching for dependency: python2_select
:debug:main Found Dependency: receipt exists for python2_select
:msg:main 
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (python27)
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 502
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (python27)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Mon Jun 15 09:32:15 CEST 2015
:notice:build --->  Building python27
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (python27)
:debug:build Environment: 
CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
CPATH='/opt/local/include'
LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.10'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.10" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all MAKE="/usr/bin/make CC=/usr/bin/clang"'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.10" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all MAKE="/usr/bin/make CC=/usr/bin/clang" 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.10'
:info:build /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.8 -c -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -pipe -Os -fwrapv -m64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/db48  -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Python/mactoolboxglue.o Python/mactoolboxglue.c
:info:build In file included from /usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:51:0,
:info:build                  from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:15,
:info:build                  from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFPropertyList.h:13,
:info:build                  from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:55,
:info:build                  from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:19,
:info:build                  from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20,
:info:build                  from Include/pymactoolbox.h:10,
:info:build                  from Python/mactoolboxglue.c:27:
:info:build /usr/include/dispatch/object.h:143:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '^' token
:info:build  typedef void (^dispatch_block_t)(void);
:info:build                ^
:info:build /usr/include/dispatch/object.h:362:3: error: unknown type name 'dispatch_block_t'
:info:build    dispatch_block_t notification_block);
:info:build    ^
:info:build make: *** [Python/mactoolboxglue.o] Error 1
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.10'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/work/Python-2.7.10" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all MAKE="/usr/bin/make CC=/usr/bin/clang" 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port python27 returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 44681 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"portbuild::build_main org.macports.build"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for python27: org.macports.install org.macports.build org.macports.destroot
:notice:build Please see the log file for port python27 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_python27/python27/main.log
```

I do not know how to solve it . Does anyone have an idea ?

Arnaud

Comment: For information, I use this https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building%20and%20installing%20HHVM%20on%20OSX%2010.9 & http://packages.corneltek.com/pkg/ for install HHVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally **solved my problem** with two series of actions:

1. with brew

`brew tap homebrew/dupes
 brew tap homebrew/versions
 brew tap mcuadros/homebrew-hhvm
 brew update
 cd $(brew --repository)
 git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
 brew update
 brew install hhvm --HEAD
 brew install ocaml
 brew link dwarfutils ocaml
 brew unlink libdwarf
 brew link dwarfutils ocaml
 brew link --overwrite ocaml
 brew link dwarfutils ocaml
 brew install hhvm --HEAD`

and after...

2. with macports

   `sudo port -v selfupdate
   port upgrade outdated
   sudo port upgrade outdated
   sudo port search ImageMagick
   sudo port install ImageMagick
   port selfupdate
   sudo port selfupdate`

An important detail , MacPorts went from **version 2.3.3 to version 2.3.4** in this update .

### MacPort is now operational again.

Answer (score 1):

same errror.

1/ `sudo port selfupdate`,

result:

```html
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
    MacPorts base version 2.3.3 installed,
    MacPorts base version 2.3.3 downloaded.
    --->  Updating the ports tree
    --->  MacPorts base is already the latest version

    The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
      port upgrade outdated
```

2/ `sudo port install -d -R valabind`

result:

```html
--->  Computing dependencies for valabind
    --->  Cleaning valabind
    --->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
    --->  Found 15 broken file(s), matching files to ports   
    --->  Found 6 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
    --->  Rebuilding in order
         valabind @0.8.0 
         ushare @1.1a 
         wget @1.14 +ssl
         geocode-glib @3.10.0 
         strigi @0.7.8 
         nepomuk-core @4.12.5 
    --->  Fetching archive for valabind
    --->  Attempting to fetch valabind-0.8.0_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/valabind
    --->  Attempting to fetch valabind-0.8.0_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/valabind
    --->  Attempting to fetch valabind-0.8.0_1.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/valabind
    --->  Computing dependencies for valabind
    --->  Fetching distfiles for valabind
    --->  Verifying checksums for valabind
    --->  Extracting valabind
    --->  Configuring valabind
    --->  Building valabind
    Error: org.macports.build for port valabind returned: command execution failed
    Please see the log file for port valabind for details:
        /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_valabind/valabind/main.log
    Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
    Error rebuilding valabind
        while executing
    "error "Error rebuilding $portname""
        (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
        invoked from within
    "revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
        (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
        invoked from within
    "macports::revupgrade $opts"
        (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
        invoked from within
    "action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
        (procedure "action_target" line 96)
        invoked from within
    "$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
        (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
        invoked from within
    "process_cmd $remaining_args"
        invoked from within
    "if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

        # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
        set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
        (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)
```

3/ `sudo port install -d -R -y valabind`

result:

```html
--->  Computing dependencies for valabind
For valabind: skipping org.macports.main (dry run)
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  Found 15 broken file(s), matching files to ports   
--->  Found 6 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     valabind @0.8.0 
     ushare @1.1a 
     wget @1.14 +ssl
     geocode-glib @3.10.0 
     strigi @0.7.8 
     nepomuk-core @4.12.5 
--->  Computing dependencies for valabind
--->  Building valabind
Error: org.macports.build for port valabind returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port valabind for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_valabind/valabind/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error rebuilding valabind
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_target" line 96)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

    # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo port install php55-pear` won't install HHVM -- it will install the standard PHP5 engine, and then add the PEAR repository to it. Furthermore, from the error message, I suspect that the issue you're having isn't with PHP at all, but is something with the Python 2.7 package. You should take this up with the MacPorts maintainers -- it certainly has nothing to do with HHVM, and probably nothing to do with PHP at all.

If you want to try building HHVM on a Mac, I've been working on getting that up and running again. [These directions on the wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/Building%20and%20installing%20HHVM%20on%20OSX%2010.10#macports-install-by-hand) are, at the time of this writing, believed to work for HHVM master. You can give them a try, though no promises they actually will work, Mac support is still super experimental. (And they probably *won't* work until you get the MacPorts issue above sorted out!)

Comment: Indeed , this has nothing to do with php. I just showed (by installing a php library) how I got the error message .

My problem is mac port. I can not install anything with .

And I have this problem since I tried to install HHVM . I would go later on a solution to install HHVM . What I want now is to be able to function properly mac port.

Answer (score 0):

My error change.

I followed what is described in this post: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40167.

I launched the command with success: 
`sudo port clean all`

And after this: 
`sudo port -d upgrade python27`

But, last result : 
`Exit code: 2
Error: org.macports.build for port valabind returned: command execution failed
DEBUG: Error code: CHILDSTATUS 70008 2
DEBUG: Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"portbuild::build_main org.macports.build"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
Warning: targets not executed for valabind: org.macports.destroot org.macports.build
Please see the log file for port valabind for details:`
    `/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_valabind/valabind/main.log
DEBUG: can not find channel named "debuglog"
    while executing
"tcl::puts debuglog {DEBUG: Starting logging for valabind}"
    invoked from within
"catch "tcl::puts $args""
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
DEBUG: Rebuilding port valabind finished with status 1
Error rebuilding valabind
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_upgrade" line 25)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {`


    `# If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)`

I try now classic code for test: `sudo port install php55-pear`

Result change but always failed:

```html
--->  Computing dependencies for php55-pear
--->  Cleaning php55-pear
--->  Updating database of binaries
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors               
--->  Found 19 broken file(s), matching files to ports   
--->  Found 7 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     gcr @3.10.1 
     ushare @1.1a 
     valabind @0.8.0 
     wget @1.14 +ssl
     geocode-glib @3.10.0 
     strigi @0.7.8 
     nepomuk-core @4.12.5 
--->  Fetching archive for libusb
--->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.19_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libusb
--->  Attempting to fetch libusb-1.0.19_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libusb
--->  Installing libusb @1.0.19_0
--->  Cleaning libusb
--->  Deactivating libusb @1.0.18_0
--->  Cleaning libusb
--->  Activating libusb @1.0.19_0
--->  Cleaning libusb
--->  Fetching archive for libusb-compat
--->  Attempting to fetch libusb-compat-0.1.5_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libusb-compat
--->  Attempting to fetch libusb-compat-0.1.5_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/libusb-compat
--->  Computing dependencies for libusb-compat
--->  Unable to uninstall libusb-compat @0.1.5_0, the following ports depend on it:
--->   gnupg @1.4.13_1
--->   gnupg @1.4.16_0
Warning: Uninstall forced.  Proceeding despite dependencies.
--->  Deactivating libusb-compat @0.1.5_0
--->  Unable to deactivate libusb-compat @0.1.5_0, the following ports depend on it:
--->   gnupg @1.4.16_0
Warning: Deactivate forced.  Proceeding despite dependencies.
--->  Cleaning libusb-compat
--->  Uninstalling libusb-compat @0.1.5_0
--->  Cleaning libusb-compat
--->  Computing dependencies for libusb-compat
--->  Installing libusb-compat @0.1.5_0
--->  Activating libusb-compat @0.1.5_0
--->  Cleaning libusb-compat
--->  Computing dependencies for gnupg
--->  Fetching archive for gnupg
--->  Attempting to fetch gnupg-1.4.19_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gnupg
--->  Attempting to fetch gnupg-1.4.19_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/gnupg
--->  Attempting to fetch gnupg-1.4.19_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://nue.de.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/gnupg
--->  Fetching distfiles for gnupg
--->  Attempting to fetch gnupg-1.4.19.tar.bz2 from http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/gnupg
--->  Verifying checksums for gnupg                                                  
--->  Extracting gnupg
--->  Applying patches to gnupg
--->  Configuring gnupg
--->  Building gnupg
--->  Staging gnupg into destroot
--->  Installing gnupg @1.4.19_0
--->  Cleaning gnupg
--->  Computing dependencies for gnupg
--->  Deactivating gnupg @1.4.16_0
--->  Cleaning gnupg
--->  Activating gnupg @1.4.19_0
--->  Cleaning gnupg
--->  Computing dependencies for gcr
--->  Fetching archive for gcr
--->  Attempting to fetch gcr-3.16.0_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gcr
--->  Attempting to fetch gcr-3.16.0_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/gcr
--->  Installing gcr @3.16.0_0
--->  Cleaning gcr
--->  Computing dependencies for gcr
--->  Deactivating gcr @3.10.1_1
--->  Cleaning gcr
--->  Activating gcr @3.16.0_0
--->  Cleaning gcr
--->  Computing dependencies for ushare
--->  Cleaning ushare
--->  Computing dependencies for valabind
--->  Building valabind
Error: org.macports.build for port valabind returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port valabind for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_valabind/valabind/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error rebuilding valabind
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 395)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_target" line 96)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 103)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

    # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5268)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pear install depends on this (broken) parts.

> ```
> --->  Found 7 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
> --->  Rebuilding in order
>       gcr @3.10.1 
>       ushare @1.1a 
>       valabind @0.8.0 
>       wget @1.14 +ssl
>       geocode-glib @3.10.0 
>       strigi @0.7.8 
>       nepomuk-core @4.12.5
> ```

Following your error results, it stopped at updating `valabind`.
What happens if you try:

```
port selfupdate
sudo port install -d -R valabind
```

If `valabind` is a dependency of your `php install` and has dependencies of itself, `port` is not able to handle this. Wether install nor upgrade acording to the `man port` page:

> ```
>  -R       also upgrade dependents (only affects upgrade) - note that this
>           does not upgrade dependents' dependencies
> ```

Check the home of valabind [here](http://radare.org) as well.

A good idea for debugging is the `port -y` option.

> ```
>  -y       Perform a dry run. All of the steps to build the ports and their
>           dependencies are computed, but not actually performed. With the
>           verbose flag, every step is reported; otherwise there is just
>           one message per port, which allows you to easily determine the
>           recursive deps of a port (and the order in which they will be
>           built).
> ```